# How to get rid of \N from pig result

Tags: apache-pig

preview of what I am supposed to change, replace the `\N` with `()` with empty string

[image]

```
 d = FOREACH result GENERATE REPLACE(REPLACE(EFF_DT,'\N','');
```

[image]

so essentially if it's a valid date should be left alone, if its `\N` it should get rid of  `\N` and supposed to show `()` but it obviously comes up as `(\)`. Just wondering why this isn't working like it supposed to. I tried the bottom one as well no help.

```
d = FOREACH result GENERATE REPLACE(REPLACE(EFF_DT,'\N',''),'\',''));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `\` and `N` are special characters here. Try this,

```
 d = FOREACH result GENERATE REPLACE(EFF_DT,'\\\\N','');
```